# How to verify text in a css class with Selenium?

Tags: css, selenium-webdriver

I am using Selenium to automate app creation test.  The test includes filling out fields on a web page and clicking a submit button.  Once that is done, a new page loads with an alert stating success or failure.  The problem for me is, the alert is coded in a css class as follows:

```
<div class="alert-box notice">
     Successfully created application
    <a href="" class="close">×</a>
</div>
```

All I need to do is verify the text "Successfully created application" exists.  I do not need to manipulate anything.

Comment: "Capture" how? To do what?  CSS can't detect content.

Comment: You can verify the text with Selenium itself. I don't understand what you intend to use CSS for, exactly.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=verify+text+selenium

Comment: I am using Selenium and simply need to verify that the text does, in fact exist.  Normally I'd use findElement but there are no identifiers for the text.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what language you are doing, but basically, you need to get the text in the containing div.

So, for example,

```
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector(".alert-box.notice")).getText()
```

Comment: When I try this, the test fails.  The trace has the following line in it:

org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":".alert-box.notice"}

Comment: @EricScott my best guess is that there is a delay before it appears.  I would recommend waiting until the element exists, and then testing for it.

Answer (score 0):

After some discussion with my peers and much online research, here is the solution I found.

At first I tried capturing the text based on Nathan's suggestion, but decided to store the results as a string.

```
String happy = driver.findElement(By.className("alert-box notice")).getText();
assertEquals(true, happy.contains("Successfully"));
```

The problem with this is that I kept getting errors such as, "org.openqa.selenium.InvalidSelectorException: The given selector alert-box notice is either invalid or does not result in a WebElement. The following error occurred:
InvalidSelectorError: Compound class names not permitted"

Since I have no control over the class name, I went the xpath route as follows:

```
String happy = driver.findElement(By.xpath("html/body/div/div[2]/div/div/div/div[3]/div")).getText();
assertEquals(true, happy.contains("Successfully"));
```

This version runs correctly and I am able to verify the alert message.